# How to redirect specific range of ports to port 80 in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

When I use the below command, I am able to redirect from port 3000 to port 80, but I need to redirect to port 80 when a request is for any other port.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Comment: I need to forward the port 80 when request port is in range 1 - 3000

Answer (score 0):

Try this command , this will helpfull.

```
pass in on tl0 proto tcp from any to any port 5000:5500 \ rdr-to 192.168.1.20
```

referred from this [link](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html)